TensorFlow on GPU: Strided_Slice Error after one successful epoch
I am using tensorflow and keras to train a Unet architecture for landmark detection. I have CUDA® Toolkit 11.8. and cuDNN SDK 8.6.0. as well as Tensorflow 2.10 installed on my Windows and the GPU is detected by tensorflow. I have tested every transformation I apply to the tensorflow dataset and the training runs smoothly on the CPU. But on the GPU, I managed to train for 1 epoch (task manager shows GPU at 100% usage, and the loss value decreases) but directly after I get this error:
2024-06-16 11:47:24.508517: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:384] Loaded cuDNN version 8600
2024-06-16 11:47:26.388357: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:360] Garbage collection: deallocate free memory regions (i.e., allocations) so that we can re-allocate a larger region to avoid OOM due to memory fragmentation. If you see this message frequently, you are running near the threshold of the available device memory and re-allocation may incur great performance overhead. You may try smaller batch sizes to observe the performance impact. Set TF_ENABLE_GPU_GARBAGE_COLLECTION=false if you'd like to disable this feature.
2024-06-16 11:47:28.638661: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:1614] TensorFloat-32 will be used for the matrix multiplication. This will only be logged once.
6/6 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 4.8601 - root_mean_squared_error: 2.20462024-06-16 11:47:35.464210: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1780] OP_REQUIRES failed at strided_slice_op.cc:111 : INVALID_ARGUMENT: Index out of range using input dim 1; input has only 1 dims
2024-06-16 11:47:35.464611: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1780] OP_REQUIRES failed at strided_slice_op.cc:111 : INVALID_ARGUMENT: Expected begin, end, and strides to be 1D equal size tensors, but got shapes [2], [19,2], and [2] instead.     
2024-06-16 11:47:35.464732: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1780] OP_REQUIRES failed at strided_slice_op.cc:111 : INVALID_ARGUMENT: Index out of range using input dim 1; input has only 1 dims
2024-06-16 11:47:35.464817: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1780] OP_REQUIRES failed at strided_slice_op.cc:111 : INVALID_ARGUMENT: Expected begin, end, and strides to be 1D equal size tensors, but got shapes [19,2], [2], and [2] instead.     
2024-06-16 11:47:35.467318: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1768] UNKNOWN: InvalidArgumentError: {{function_node __wrapped__StridedSlice_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0}} Index out of range using input dim 1; input has only 1 dims [Op:StridedSlice] name: strided_slice/
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\jadak\miniconda3\envs\py310tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\script_ops.py", line 269, in __call__
    return func(device, token, args)

  File "C:\Users\jadak\miniconda3\envs\py310tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\script_ops.py", line 147, in __call__
    outputs = self._call(device, args)

  File "C:\Users\jadak\miniconda3\envs\py310tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\script_ops.py", line 154, in _call
    ret = self._func(*args)

  File "C:\Users\jadak\miniconda3\envs\py310tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\impl\api.py", line 642, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "c:\Users\jadak\Documents\Papillons\code\utils.py", line 116, in convertToHM
    x = keypoints[i,1].numpy()

The error is puzzling since the buffer fills the first time and the training occurs in epoch one, and I verified these things and with a few prints I see that it detects well the scalar values in the "keypoints" tensor. I don't even use strided slices willingly. Convolutional layers do exist in the Unet architecture but has no relation with the keypoints and the shape of the 19 keypoints mentionned in the error. I got the same error on my local gpu as well as on Paperspace GPU.
Please some insight or some help would benefit me greatly since I on a tight schedule for model delivery.
I can provide the codes upon demand.
For now I can show the clear ambiguity of the error between epoch 1 and 2:
# Convert an image to an heatmap
def convertToHM(img, keypoints, sigma, prob_function):
    H = img.shape[0]
    W = img.shape[1]
    nKeypoints = len(keypoints)
    # print('nnnnn', nKeypoints)
    img_hm = np.zeros(shape=(H, W), dtype=np.float32)
    # print('ggggg', keypoints.shape)
    for i in range(0, nKeypoints):
        try:
            x = keypoints[i][1].numpy()
            print('x', x)
            y = keypoints[i][0].numpy()
        except:
            print('errrrrrrrrrror', keypoints)
            continue
        if i == 0:
            channel_hm = _exp(x, y, sigma, H, W) if prob_function == 'exp' else _gaussian(x, y, sigma, H, W)
        else:
            channel_hm += _exp(x, y, sigma, H, W) if prob_function == 'exp' else _gaussian(x, y, sigma, H, W)
        img_hm[:, :] = channel_hm
    
    img_hm = np.reshape(img_hm, newshape=(img_hm.shape[0]*img_hm.shape[1], 1))
    return img, img_hm

And the result:
x 175.0
x 170.0
x 171.0
x 153.0
x 155.0
x 154.0
x 151.0
x 137.0
x 162.0
x 160.0
x 155.0
x 143.0
x 156.0
x 156.0
x 151.0
x 140.0
2024-06-16 13:35:27.600234: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:384] Loaded cuDNN version 8600
2024-06-16 13:35:28.350322: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:360] Garbage collection: deallocate free memory regions (i.e., allocations) so that we can re-allocate a larger region to avoid OOM due to memory fragmentation. If you see this message frequently, you are running near the threshold of the available device memory and re-allocation may incur great performance overhead. You may try smaller batch sizes to observe the performance impact. Set TF_ENABLE_GPU_GARBAGE_COLLECTION=false if you'd like to disable this feature.
2024-06-16 13:35:29.790269: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:1614] TensorFloat-32 will be used for the matrix multiplication. This will only be logged once.
6/6 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.1686 - root_mean_squared_error: 1.0810x 147
2024-06-16 13:35:36.586307: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1780] OP_REQUIRES failed at strided_slice_op.cc:111 : INVALID_ARGUMENT: Expected begin, end, and strides to be 1D equal size tensors, but got shapes [1], [19,2], and [19,2] instead.  
errrrrrrrrrror tf.Tensor(
[[129 147]
 [146 184]
 [161 201]
 [181 206]
 [199 202]
 [211 192]
 [216 178]
 [216 165]
 [142 135]
 [143 136]
 [161 153]
 [164 159]
 [164 162]
 [163 164]
 [153 161]
 [146 154]
 [141 140]
 [135 147]
 [135 143]], shape=(19, 2), dtype=int32)2024-06-16 13:35:36.587632: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1780] OP_REQUIRES failed at strided_slice_op.cc:111 : INVALID_ARGUMENT: Index out of range using input dim 0; input has only 0 dims
errrrrrrrrrror tf.Tensor(
[[138 135]
 [161 184]
 [183 200]
 [198 199]
 [216 191]
 [227 179]


Apparently the indices are fine, the problem is about memory leaks and GPU not having access to the tensor itself. Anyone knows how to handle this ??
